# Array Push not working with Real Time

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, pusher

I'm using Pusher for Angular Webapp for Real Time Application. I need add to array products a new item when other add a item from form in other session. In my sessión it's works. In another session the data obtained if it is added to the array but not shown in the ng-repeat.

Controller:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','Products',function($scope,Products) {
    $scope.products = Products.getAll();
    var pusher = new Pusher('MY KEY', {
      encrypted: true
    });

    $scope.addProduct = function(product){
        Products.addProduct(product);
    }

    var callback = function(data) {
        $scope.products.push(data.NewProduct);
        console.log($scope.products);
    };

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('products');
    channel.bind('addProduct', callback);
}]);
```

View:

```
<tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in products track by product.id">
          <td >{{product.name}}</td>
          <td>{{product.unity}}</td>
          <td>{{product.price}}</td>
          <td>
            <button>
              Edit
            </button>
            <button>
              Delete
            </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

Comment: Might be the issue with angular digest cycle!. Try wrapping your `callback` in `$evalAsync`

Comment: Thanks @GangadharJannu,but I still do not understand how I could do it.

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44582823/3543808)

Answer (score 0):

> [$evalAsync](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$evalAsync) Executes the expression on the current scope at a later point in time.

So add $evalAsync to callback function in your code

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$evalAsync','Products',function($scope,$evalAsync, Products) {
    $scope.products = Products.getAll();
    var pusher = new Pusher('MY KEY', {
      encrypted: true
    });

    $scope.addProduct = function(product){
        Products.addProduct(product);
    }

    var callback = function(data) {
        $scope.products.push(data.NewProduct);
        console.log($scope.products);
    };

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('products');
    channel.bind('addProduct', $evalAsync(callback));
}]);
```

Comment: No, i did it like this:

var callback = function(data) {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.products.push(data.Producto);
            });
            console.log($scope.products);
        };

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
var callback = function(data) {
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                $scope.products.push(data.Producto);
            });
            console.log($scope.products);
        };
```